# Wrong error message for small changes

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

This is the error I got after sending a suggested edit via the android app:

> [image]

I only changed a single character. It mattered!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are quoted images automatically scaled down?

Comment: Nope, I have added "l" to the image name, thus using a pre-made scaled image. imgur trick I learned here a while ago. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Oooh. Nice. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: My pleasure, use it wisely! ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You can use "m" and "s" too (small, medium, large). S is usually pointless, and often M reduces too much, but worth knowing them all :)

Comment: @James: Ah, very cool. Thanks for the update. Now it's also a bit easier to remember. I didn't quite make the connection why "L" would scale down ;D